# Any reason to scan gas giants?

Tags: star-control-2

StarControl II (these days called [Ur-Quan Masters](http://sc2.sourceforge.net/)) has quite a lot of grinding in terms of scanning planets for minerals, life forms and energy beacons. Gas giants seem to always produce empty scans. Is there a reason to ever visit\scan gas giants in StarControl II?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no, there is no reason to visit gas giants. There are no resources to be found on them.

However, there is one important exception: One single gas giant in the galaxy should be visited as it holds something special.

**SPOILER:**

> The Slylandro are the only species who have a gas giant as a homeworld: Beta Corvi IV. Visiting this planet is necessary to put a stop to the random attacks by the red tumbling drones.

Comment: Do you need to discover this specific case by yourself, or do you get a hint about it from some conversation? If the latter is true, then indeed I can stop visiting them...

Comment: @jonathan, it is possible to get this information in-game.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope.**

You can't land on them, therefore you can't collect anything from them. The best you can hope for is a moon with something worth collecting.